# How to create a boolean property/binding whose value is based on an integer?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to create a class which holds boolean information via an `int`: if its value is greater than 0 the boolean's value is `true`, otherwise `false`.

This is a class that encapsulates this behavior:

```
public class CumulativeBoolean {

    private int cumulative = 0;

    public boolean get() {
        return cumulative > 0;
    }

    public void set(boolean val) {
        cumulative += val ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

I want to create a JavaFX class from this design that allows binding and listening. I looked at extending either `BooleanBinding` or `BooleanPropertyBase`, they both hold a `private boolean value` as their value while what I want is an `int`.

This is what I have for `BooleanBinding`:

```
public class CumulativeBooleanBinding extends BooleanBinding {

    private int cumulative = 0;

    public void set(boolean val) {
        cumulative += val ? 1 : -1;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean computeValue() {
        return cumulative != 0;
    }
}
```

However, I don't think that the idea of `BooleanBinding` was to support a `set` functionality, and there is also the issue of setting the value while the value is bound.

`BooleanPropertyBase`, on the other hand, does not allow me to invalidate when updating since its `markInvalid` method and `valid` fields are private.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: What are your actual requirements? You seem to want two values, a boolean and an integer, that are bound so that the boolean is true if and only if the integer is positive. But what API do you want? Do you want to be able to set the boolean (and if so, what should happen to the integer when you change the boolean)? Do you want to be able to set the integer as well?

Comment: Your implementations really don't work anyway: if you call `x.set(true);` `x.set(true);` `x.set(false);`, then `x.get()` returns `true`, which is definitely not the expected behavior of `get()` and `set()`.

Comment: @James_D Here is a use case: an action must require the agreement of all people. A person can veto the action by setting their vote to `true` and remove it by setting it to `false`. When it is checked if the action can be taken it is checked if there is at least 1 veto. The action must have a boolean that reflects this state, via, e.g., `canTakeAction()`. It is required to be possible to bind to that boolean. The boolean cannot be changed directly. The integer cannot be set, but only incremented and decremented (add/remove veto). Your example shows correct behavior.

Comment: @James_D That is to say, the integer is an implementation detail, the boolean is the API.

Comment: It's "correct" in the sense that you can use the `set` method to achieve the functionality you want, but it's not "semantically correct": that is simply not the expected behavior of `set()` and `get()` (specifically: if you call `x.set(y)` then `x.get()` should return `y` if no modifications occur in between the calls, *irrespective of any previous state of `x`*). So your `BooleanBinding` subclass works fine, but you should rename the `set` method, say, to `veto(boolean shouldVeto)` (or similar).

Comment: I guess what I mean here is that if you are looking to inherit or implement an existing `set` method, you really can't do so, because you want functionality that is different to the `set` functionality defined or specified in existing classes and interfaces. So simply subclass `BooleanBinding` and add in the additional functionality, suitably named.

Comment: @James_D O.K., the names of the methods are debatable, it's not what bothered me. I was worried that this is not how `BooleanBinding` was meant to be subclassed, but the more I look at it the more it seems fine. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the discussion in the comments I ended up with the `BooleanBinding`-based design in my question. To remove the confusion relating to the expectation from `set` I renamed it to something like `add`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the binding-functionality of JavaFX, you have to use a ObservableValue (such as SimpleIntegerProperty).

The following code shows a quick example how to implement it:

```
SimpleIntegerProperty intProp = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
BooleanBinding binding = intProp.greaterThanOrEqualTo(0);
```

If you don't want to use an ObservableValue of Integer in your class, the other option is to update a BooleanProperty when setting your int:

```
SimpleBooleanProperty fakeBinding = new SimpleBooleanProperty(value >= 0);
```

and after every call to the set method:

```
fakeBinding.set(value >= 0);
```

EDIT: Seems like MBec was faster than me :p

Comment: But then I need to update the integer property with a number, while I need to update it with a boolean. I don't understand your second options, where is the integer value held?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be easier to create `IntegerProperty` and then create `BooleanBinding` from that property? Like this:

```
IntegerProperty cumulative = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
BooleanBinding greaterThanZeroCumulative = cumulative.greaterThan(0);
```

Comment: But then I need to update the integer property with a number, while I need to update it with a boolean.